# Is there a restriction on the order of the PDO array insert values?

Tags: php, pdo

I am changing an existing data storage php code from `mysql_*` functions to PDO as well changing it from Procedural to OOB programming. I was updating the SQL statements when I noticed something, fairly far into the rewriting process.

I am setting up an array for multiple tables `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, as I was defining an array to work as the binding values I noticed that the *order* in which the bound values are called would be different from the `UPDATE` to the `INSERT`, here is a brief example:

```
$bound_values = array(
    ':column_aa' => 'aa',
    ':column_ab' => 'ab',
    ':column_ac' => 'ac'
    )
);
```

Example sql for `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `table_a` 
    (`id`, `column_aa`, `column_ab`, `column_ac`) 
VALUES 
    ('', :column_aa, :column_ab, :column_ac);
```

and the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `table_a` SET 
    `column_ab` = :column_ab, `column_ac` = :column_ac, `column_aa` = :column_aa;
```

Example PHP PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'root', '');
// The second parameter of the PDO cursor is what I saw that raised the flag
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute($boud_values);
```

So my question is, can I keep going forward using this method without an issue as to what order the SQL statements are in vs the `$bound_values` array, or am I right in being concerned and need to make some changes?

Please note that the existing code I am working with isn't anywhere **near** as simple as the SQL statements I have shown above.

Comment: So long as you are using named identifiers and not simply `?` then it does not matter what order the array is in.

Comment: Great news, that's why I started using named identifiers but every example I saw had them in order and then seeing the `CURSOR_FWDONLY` I started to worry. Thanks @sammitich, if you would be so kind please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Just accept, @robert-widdick's. It's equally right, and he could use some points. ;D

Comment: Why can't you just experiment a bit and decide yourself? I am not accusing but just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using named placeholders (:col_name), you can put them in any order as you please. However, using positional placeholders (?) - you need to put them in order.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter as long as you use named parameters ( `:somename` ). The binding simply tells your database engine "where I wrote the placeholder `:abc`, fill with this value. Where I wrote placeholder `:xyz`, put this other value".

Think about how the code would look like if you were binding each value separately instead of all at once in the execute

```
$sth->bindParam(':abc', 'value1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':xyz', 'value2', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Switching the bindParam() order would not have any impact.

Also, note that the order in which the column are set in INSERT and UPDATE sql queries doesn't matter, so if this really bugs you (or if you like things to be standardized a little) you can just order the column the same way in both queries.

```
UPDATE table SET col2 = 'xyz', col1 = 'abc'
// is the same as
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'abc', col2 = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Lack of standardization or consistency is a BIG pet peeve of mine, so eventually the `UPDATE` statements will reflect the order of the columns / `INSERT` statements, but there are too many queries and too little time at the moment. Thank you for the answer and explanation +1